# Intellij "Run as Android application" missing

Tags: android, intellij-idea, genymotion

The emulator android is really running slowy, and I found Genymotion and runs really fast! And when I tried to use with Intellij, after I followed every step from this doc `https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/`, I got stuck in this item:

> In your application project, right click and chose "Run as Android
>   application" The "Android Devices Chooser" opens Click on the
>   Genymotion virtual device you started/created

I really can't find "Run as Android application" whenever I click on my folder project, where I'm missing?

Look at this image, I really don't know why.
http://i42.tinypic.com/2ia76rl.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the toolbar of Intellij. There is a drop down menu (next to it are the "play" button and the "bug" button to start the debugger). You need to setup an Android configuration for your project first.
Check this site
   http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html.

Although I have a configuration for my project, like you I can't see it in the menu your screenshot is showing. But I can use the mentioned run button to run my project without any problem.

Good luck.

Comment: Just adding one more info, need to choose "Show chooser Dialog" and not from "Emulator", Thanks!

Comment: You are right. That's a common mistake and if you miss it you are wondering why the emulator doesn't start. :)

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ inside the *Run/Debug Configuration* dialog (available under *Edit configurations...*) you have to select radiobutton "**Show chooser dialog**" instead of Emulator.

Then you just press *Run* and you get the list of running devices.

If you select "*Use same device for future launches*" in the configuration dialog, you won't have to select the device again next time.

Answer (score 0):

On your screenshot you have a "Run" item on the options. Look at what appears when you let your mouse over it ;-)

Comment: I know, but there's nothing showing on that "Run" ... "Android Application" item. That's why I'm asking, where's the damn "Android Application".